# Is it possible to extract only the visible contents of a scroll-able div?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `<div>` with `overflow: auto;` and enough content to require vertical scrolling.

Is there a way, using PLAIN JAVASCRIPT, to extract only the visible content (HTML) in the `<div>`? (that is, only what is visibile on the screen based on the current scollbar position). Note - the container doesn't have to be a `<div>`.

Comment: What is the use case? This is far from a simple task depending on level of accuracy expected

Comment: If I have a table of contents on one side of the container I want to be able to highlight - in the table of the contents - the section that is currently visible. I'd also like to be able to have a separate div on the other side that lists any abbreviations/definitions that are in the visible content of the main div...

Comment: do some web searching there are lots of scripts and plugins around for doing this. Just need to use some attributes on the elements

Comment: I have, but haven't found any that use plain javascript...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, as long as you don't mind applying some `position` to your container. Once you've applied positioning, you can then get the `offset` of the child element(s) relative to its parent's `height` (and `width`, if desired) and then determine if the element is visible.

Here's a simple fiddle I threw together tested in Chrome only, so use at your own risk! ;)

http://jsfiddle.net/7nz1kfyx/

The relevant JS:

```
function isElementVisible (el, parent) {
    return (el.offsetTop + el.clientHeight) <= (parent.clientHeight);
}
```

You could add additional logic to the returned condition (for instance, checking against the `offsetLeft` of an element relative to it's parent to see if it's actually visible...)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible but its extremely hacky using

```
document.elementFromPoint(x,y)
```

So you would iterate through the bounding box of your div query the screen buffer, and collect the elements returned.

see http://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM:document.elementFromPoint for more detailed API documentation